# Flask SQLAlchemy unique constraint on multiple columns with a given value

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Let say I have two tables

Order table

```
class Order(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  deliveries = db.relationship("Delivery", back_populates="order")
```

Delivery table

```
class Delivery(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  status= db.Column(db.String(20))
  order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order.id'), nullable=False)
  order = db.relationship("Order", back_populates="deliveries")
```

One order may have many deliveries. The status field of delivery table has following possible values `["Planned", "Failed", "Delivered"]`

**Question:**
How can make sure that one order does not have two planned deliveries ?

**Tips:**
I know I can implemt unique constraint on multiple tables like adding below line to delivery schema

`__table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('order_id', 'status', name='_order_status_uc'))`

But by doing so I will prevent one order from having two failed deliveries.

Any help will be greatly appreciate as I want to enforce this constraint directly in the db.

Comment: What is the database engine you are using?

Comment: Am using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

**Update (given it is PostgreSQL)**

Given you use PostgreSQL, the most straightforward solution is to use [Partial Unique Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3):

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX _order_status_uc ON delivery (order_id) WHERE status = 'Planned';`

If you use SQLAlchemy to create the index, the below should be equivalent:

class Delivery(Base):
# ...

```
__table_args__ = (
    Index(
        '_order_status_uc',
        'order_id',
        unique=True,
        postgresql_where=(status == 'Planned'),
    ),
)
```

**Original answer**

Assuming the RDBMS you are using supports this, one implementation idea would be to do as follows:

- create a computed column on `delivery` table which would have value of `order_id` for "Planned" `status` and `NULL` otherwise
- create a `UNIQUE Constraint` on this computed column.

This assumes the following regarding used RDBMS:

1. Computed columns are not only supported but also can be part of the index/constraint.
2. the implementation of UNIQUE index is such that multiple `NULL` values are allowed.

Please see [PostgreSQL unique constraint null: Allowing only one Null](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/postgresql-unique-constraint-null-allowing-only-one-null) article for more background.

Comment: _I am sure someone will think of a solution with more relaxed constraints though._

Comment: If PostgreSQL, partial unique index on order_id with `status = 'Planned'`? I bet that is why you have already asked about the DBMS.

Comment: So far I did not manage to find a well fit constraint implementation. This proposition is a workaround and I took it. Thanks a lot @van

Answer (score 0):

You could query your delivery model with the current order id and status planned, if there is a result, raise validation.

```
planned_delivery_exist_boolean = db.session.query(Delivery).filter(Delivery.order_id==order_id).filter(Delivery.status=="Planned").first()

if planned_delivery_exist_boolean:
    # trigger validation error
```

Comment: This can work only on ORM level. I want something on database level reason why am looking for a db constraint